# Samsung S21 freeze issue during track stopage

Tags: javascript, frontend, video-streaming, media, samsung-mobile

For some reason stoppage of stream track (https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop)
causes complete freeze of browser.

Issue is only reproduced in Samsung S21 device (works fine in S20 and others for example).

Has anyone faced this issue and what can be done in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add more details about your issue? Is it a web page? What tools are you using?

Comment: Yes it is web page. I'm using React, but it is reproducible even in vanilla js.